Artifactory Query Language - find all packages depending on specific package
I am trying to write a one-off query in AQL (Artifactory Query Language) and I am having difficulty due to a lack of layman accessible knowledge (I am not a dedicated DevOps professional).
I'd like an AQL query that gets all packages (artefacts) in my Artifactory NuGet repository foo that depend on NuGet package bar version 1.2.3. I'd think it would have to be something like this:
items.find({"repo": "foo", "@dependencies": {"$includes", "bar.1.2.3"}}).include("name")

but this is not working. I can't find concrete examples of how to deal with collections in artefact metadata in the official documentation and I'm at a loss.
Would an Artifactory guru be so kind to share how I could tackle this?
Thank you in advance!
